# How to have make build from one directory if the source file exists, otherwise build from another?

Tags: makefile

I'm working on modifying a huge recursive makefile project that has 6000+ source files.  All of which are clearcase controlled.  Since I don't want to copy the whole source tree, I'm trying to create a new project only containing the modified source files and thus pull the source from the original tree if they don't exist in my modified tree.

[image: Dir Structure]

I have already modified the makefile in `ModDir` to check if each folder exists locally and execute make in that folder if it does.  Otherwise it executes make in the `sourceDir`.  My issue lies in the subdir makefiles.

Each subdir makefile contains a list of all of the source files needed for that module.  I need to find a way to build the file locally if it exists, else build the file from `SourceDir/subdir`.

I.e. in my image, the `Dir1` makefile needs to build `F1` from `ModDir/Dir1/F1`, and build the other files from `SourceDir/Dir1/F2-F3`.

I tried to use VPATH to tell make to locate the source files in both locations (`ModDir` first of course) which works beautifully.  However, since make assumes the object files are in the `ModDir`, it can't find any of the object files built in `SourceDir`.

I also tried making a pre-build rule to modify the make file list with bash, but I don't know if that's even possible.

How do I use make to build from one directory if the source file exists (`ModDir`), otherwise build from another (`SourceDir`)?

Comment: "[Make can't find any of the object files built in `SourceDir`." It's probably best not to use those files at all, since strictly speaking the new makefiles don't have the power to build them.

Comment: Couldn't you populate `ModDir` with symbolic links to the missing source files? Or even make a third tree consisting of symbolic links to files in `SourceDir` and `ModDir` as appropriate?

Comment: Yes, I could use symlinks but I'd prefer not to clutter up ModDir.  For now, I've added the full path in each ModDir makefile to each file located in SourceDir.  This works well, but I was hoping to automate the process.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way will be to put your "if ... then ... else" logic in an external bash or batch (whichever OS you use) script and swap `makefile`s before calling `make`